# Check to see if php is installed php -V

Tags: php

I am trying to see if php is installed. I try to run `php -v` but I get this as an output. Any ideas on what is wrong?

```
(33)$ php -V
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/apc.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/apc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/ldap.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/ldap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/memcache.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/memcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/soap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite3.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/xmlreader.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/xmlreader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/xmlrpc.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/xmlrpc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/xmlwriter.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/xmlwriter.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/xsl.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/xsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Usage: php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]
       php [options] -r <code> [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -R <code> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] [-B <begin_code>] -F <file> [-E <end_code>] [--] [args...]
       php [options] -- [args...]
       php [options] -a

  -a               Run as interactive shell
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
  -n               No php.ini file will be used
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
  -f <file>        Parse and execute <file>.
  -h               This help
  -i               PHP information
  -l               Syntax check only (lint)
  -m               Show compiled in modules
  -r <code>        Run PHP <code> without using script tags <?..?>
  -B <begin_code>  Run PHP <begin_code> before processing input lines
  -R <code>        Run PHP <code> for every input line
  -F <file>        Parse and execute <file> for every input line
  -E <end_code>    Run PHP <end_code> after processing all input lines
  -H               Hide any passed arguments from external tools.
  -s               Output HTML syntax highlighted source.
  -v               Version number
  -w               Output source with stripped comments and whitespace.
  -z <file>        Load Zend extension <file>.

  args...          Arguments passed to script. Use -- args when first argument
                   starts with - or script is read from stdin

  --ini            Show configuration file names

  --rf <name>      Show information about function <name>.
  --rc <name>      Show information about class <name>.
  --re <name>      Show information about extension <name>.
  --ri <name>      Show configuration for extension <name>.
```

Comment: Looks like it is installed, but not properly. You are missing most extentions during the load process. Did you use a manual or packaged installer?

Comment: It was installed by my manager/admin.

Comment: Not very well it seems :)

Comment: So are all of those extensions set by default to come with php?

Comment: @GuyLeStack xdebug is never included by default. Looks like the [`extension_dir`](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir) config directive is incorrect.

Comment: I am pretty sure most of them aren't turned on by default (turning them on/off is done via PHP.ini) but a bunch of these are rather common and you would probably want them turned on and working (PDO, MySQL etc).

Comment: Open your php.ini file and check the extension directory. Make sure that it matches the location of the actual extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your flavor of Linux but here's a quick rundown of how it works, at least under RedHat

If you compile your own PHP, you'll likely compile these extensions as well and then load them into `php.ini`. But in packages (like `php-mysql`), you can't do that. So many flavors will set up `/etc/php.d` and you'll find all the ini files (i.e. xdebug.ini) that contain the reference to the compiled (.so) files. These are loaded at runtime, just like Apache loads all the *.conf files at runtime.

There's a few possibilities here

1. Your PHP is misconfigured and is looking at the wrong directory.
2. You don't have permissions to access that directory from the command line (if PHP works under the web server this could be the case)
3. Something else (i.e. selinux) is causing issues

So see if you can access `/usr/lib64/php/modules` and make sure the .so files are there. If not, figure out where they live. The directive is called [config-file-scan-dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-scanned-files.php)